# React js sending json to Spring boot Request failed with status code 400

Tags: json, reactjs, spring-boot, axios

I'm trying to send a state created in the front react js part to the backend spring boot part and read my state in JSON mode, I used Axios but I get this error:

Request failed with status code 400

my frontend code :

```
onSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const FilterRegion={
      //region
     eu:this.state.eu,
      americas:this.state.americas,
      aae:this.state.aae,
      ger:this.state.ger,
      eu2:this.state.eu2,
      latam : this.state.latam,
      empty:this.state.empty,
      allregion:this.state.allregion,
       }
    console.log(FilterRegion)
    axios.get("http://localhost:8080/MenuFiltre/filtreregioncloser",FilterRegion)
  }
```

Controller in back end :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/MenuFiltre")
@RestController
@CrossOrigin()
public class MenuFiltre {
    @GetMapping("/filtreregioncloser")
    public Iterable<Closerfprfx>gettab1(@RequestBody String jsonStr)
    {
        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
         System.out.println(jsonStr);

        return null;

        
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Trying taking React out of the equation for a second and try it in `Postman`. Check if your url matches in both React and Postman match. I would also provide what your "filteredRegion" object looks like. I don't think you can pass your object as you do. Could be wrong but since you are calling the "get" method, I would have thought you'd have to pass a string with eu='a'&=americas='a'&=..... Maybe it is handled by axios automatically, but I doubt it. Someone else might confirm this.

Comment: It is not suggested to use Get with body. You can try changing the get to POST in both react and spring-boot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you can remove the `@Controller` annotation from your controller as you already have the `@RestController` annotation to make it a rest controller. Secondly, if yoou want to have a request body or json send to the endpoint use a POST request. If you ask me why not to use a Request body with a GET request, the short version is it's because of HTTP spec, read : [HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body)

The http status code 400 is basically because of Bad request. The issue is with your controller endpoint. You are sending the data as json from your ui . Instead of reading the data as a string from the request body, use a pojo class like `FilterRegion`:

```
@PostMapping("/filtreregioncloser")
public Iterable<Closerfprfx>gettab1(@RequestBody FilterRegion filterRegion)
{
     //No need for Jsonobject while using POJO springboot will convert it for you from json to POJO
     System.out.println(filterRegion);
     return null;      
}
```

Create the POJO class `FilterRegion` with the fields in the json like :

```
class FilterRegion {
 String eu;
 String americas;
 //Add other fields and the constructor,getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score -1):

change your code as below:

```
axios.get("http://localhost:8080/MenuFiltre/filtreregioncloser",JSON.stringify(FilterRegion))
```